# GoRatchet don´t call onload after href

Tags: html, ratchet

When do i use a href with the ratchet framework, the navigated page doesn't use the body onload function.

```
<a class="icon icon-left-nav pull-left" href="overview.html" data-ignore="push"></a>
```

Why does the href block the onload function from overview.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t found an answer but a way to avoid this bug,
I setup an onclick event and set the href function in 
the script.